# Weird mismatched data types in Java

Tags: java, casting, geometry

When working with geometric primitives like Rectangles and Dimensions the constructors only allow for ints to be passed in, yet the getHeight and getWidth methods return doubles. This is causing me to cast to int all over the place in my code, and it is starting to look ugly.
What is up with the mismatch of the ints you pass in versus the Doubles you get out?

Answer (score 1):

Dimension implements interface Dimension2D, which supposed to be a general purpose width-height dimension, not specifically a dimension in pixel value. For generality they use double on Dimension2D, but for Dimension as in dimension in pixel value, only int makes sense.

Unfortunately overriding a method cannot change it's return type, so here we go.

Comment: So when I use the getHeight Method for Rectangles and/or Dimensions I just have to live with getting the result as a double? Looks like I can't do anything about my casts.

Comment: I am creating a rectangle with the same height a an image, but the image's getHeight method returns  double, and the rectangle constructor requires an int, hence the cast.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use double when setting up the values.

```
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.setRect(5.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0);
```

It is not a constructor, though.